# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client C# getting only User created Lists (and not Document Libraries)

Tags: list, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve a list of user generated Lists from a specified website. I do not want System generated lists (eg MicroFeed) nor Document Libraries. Using the Microsoft example I have this code:

```
    public static void LoadLists(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web, List<String> foldersList)
    {
        var ctx = web.Context;
        ListCollection collList = web.Lists;

        IEnumerable<List> listInfo = ctx.LoadQuery(
            collList.Include(
                list => list.Title,
                list => list.Fields.Include(
                    field => field.Title,
                    field => field.InternalName)));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (List oList in listInfo)
        {
            FieldCollection collField = oList.Fields;

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field oField in collField)
            {
                Regex regEx = new Regex("name", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                if (regEx.IsMatch(oField.InternalName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List: {0} \n\t Field Title: {1} \n\t Field Internal Name: {2}",
                        oList.Title, oField.Title, oField.InternalName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However this returns all Lists and Document Libraries (and heaven knows what else). Is there an easy way to just get back the user defined lists? Here is an example of what I would like to get:

[image]

And looking at the documentation from Microsoft they seems to use the term list to refer to actual lists (tables) and document libraries (folders). What is the proper nomenclature for getting the list that is really just like an excel spreadsheet of data? Finally, is it possible for lists (tables) to be nested in side a Document Libraries? I can't seem to be able to do this, but I wanted to check since I am new to SharePoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after having to lookup lots of examples (not from Microsoft, thank you) and stepping thru actual responses, here is the code for loading only the Lists and their field columns (not hidden) created by the user. I am sure that this could be optimized/cleaned up (for example not having to run the secondary queries to get List attributes, but it gave me access denied in original query), but it is working for me. Also needs some loving care for try-catches in case things go south.

First a couple of classes to hold the data:

```
public class SharePointColumn
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string InternalName { get; set; }
    public string TypeAsString { get; set; }
}

public class SharePointLibrary
{
    public SharePointLibrary()
    {
        Columns = new List<SharePointColumn>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsList { get; set; } // If true a list, else DocumentLibrary
    public List<SharePointColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Then the real code.

```
    public static void LoadLists(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web, List<SharePointLibrary> sharePointLibraries)
    {
        var ctx = web.Context;
        ListCollection collList = web.Lists;

        IEnumerable<List> listInfo = ctx.LoadQuery(
            collList.Include(
                list => list.Title,
                list => list.Fields.Include(
                    field => field.Title,
                    field => field.InternalName,
                    field => field.Hidden,
                    field => field.TypeAsString)));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (List oList in listInfo)
        {
            // Had to add these because trying to add in above query failed 
            ctx.Load(oList);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            // 544 Base Template is MicroFeed
            if (oList.Hidden == false && oList.IsCatalog == false && (!oList.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("IsSiteAssetsLibrary") || oList.IsSiteAssetsLibrary == false) && 
                oList.BaseType != BaseType.DocumentLibrary && oList.BaseTemplate != 544)
            {
                FieldCollection collField = oList.Fields;

                SharePointLibrary lib = new SharePointLibrary
                {
                    Title = oList.Title,
                    IsList = true,
                    Columns = new List<SharePointColumn>()
                };

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field oField in collField)
                {
                    if (!oField.Hidden)
                    {
                        SharePointColumn col = new SharePointColumn();
                        col.Title = oField.Title;
                        col.InternalName = oField.InternalName;
                        col.TypeAsString = oField.TypeAsString;
                        lib.Columns.Add(col);
                    }
                }

                sharePointLibraries.Add(lib);
            }
        }
    }
```